# Knowing when the letter is in the word or not

Tags: java, if-statement, error-handling

I want to know if the letter in my hangman game is in the word or not but I kept bumping into the wrong output. Anyways here is my code, this is the same one that I posted a question.

```
package besingaPi_LE_3_2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class GameHangman {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int miss = 0; 
        String choice1;
        String temp;
        
        String[] words = {"giraffe", "hippopotamus", "gorilla", "peacock", "armadillo", "rhinoceros", "alligator", "tamaraw", "chinchilla", "salamander"};

        int choice;
        int choice2;
        mainMenu();
        choice = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
        do {
            if(choice == 1){
                
                String wordRandom = Randomizer(words);
                String mute  = secretWord(wordRandom);
                temp = mute;

                System.out.println(wordRandom);
                System.out.println("Note: use only small character/s\nHint: Animals");
                
                while(!mute.equals(wordRandom)) {
                    System.out.print("(Guess) Enter a letter in word " + mute + " > ");         
                    choice1 = input.nextLine();
                    
                    mute = CharacterSearch(wordRandom, mute, choice1);
                    
                    ErrorHandling(temp, mute, choice1);
        
                    temp = mute;
    
                }
                System.out.println("The word is " + wordRandom + "." + " You missed " + miss + " time.");
                System.out.println("\nDo you want to guess another word? Enter [1]Yes or [0]No");
                System.out.print("Please input your choice: ");
                choice2 = input.nextInt();
                input.nextLine();
                System.out.println();
                if(choice2 == 1) {
                    continue;
                }
                else if(choice2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Thank you!!");
                    return;
                }

            }
            else if (choice == 0) {
                System.out.println("Thank you!!");
                return;
            }
        }while(choice != 0);

    }
    public static void mainMenu() {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Hangman");  
        System.out.println("[1]START\n[0]EXIT"); 
        System.out.print("Please input your choice: ");
        return; 
    }
    
    public static void ErrorHandling(String first, String second, String choice1) {
        int miss = 0;
        if(first.equals(second)) {
            for(int i = 0; i < second.length(); i++) {
                if(choice1.charAt(0) == second.charAt(i)){
                    System.out.println( choice1 + " is already in the word.");
                    continue;
                }
            }
            System.out.println( choice1 + " is not in the word.");
            miss++;
        }

        
    }
    
    public static String CharacterSearch(String word, String muted, String key) {
        StringBuilder update = new StringBuilder(muted);
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            if(word.charAt(i)  == key.charAt(0)) {
                update.setCharAt(i,key.charAt(0));
            }
        }
        
        muted = update.toString();
        return muted;
    }
    
    public static String secretWord(String word) {
        String temp = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            temp = temp + "*";
        }
        return temp;
    }
    
    public static String Randomizer(String[] words) {
        int rand = (int)(Math.random() * words.length);
        String word = words[rand];
        return word;
    }
}
```

If I output twice, let's say the word is "alligator", first input: a, it's okay the second input says "h is already in the word." & "h is not in the word." how to fix this? It is in the method ErrorHandling().

Comment: `if (! wordRandom.contains(choice1)) { /* The random word does not contain choice1 */ } else { /* It does. */ }`

Comment: it was fixed but the miss counter didn't increment

Comment: "the miss counter" only exists in the scope of `ErrorHandling`. Your code could use refactoring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would *refactor* your code, reviewing what you have posted I would start by moving the call to `ErrorHandling` before `CharacterSearch` and I would make it return a `boolean` so I could count the `miss`(es) in one place. I would remove the methods that don't add aid clarity, and align the variable names to be consistent. I would also recommend you follow Java naming guidelines and make the method names indicate what they do. `CharacterSearch` *really* is for updating `muted`. And `ErrorHandling` checks if the `word` has the character (or has already been chosen). I would make it something like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] words = { "giraffe", "hippopotamus", "gorilla", "peacock", 
            "armadillo", "rhinoceros", "alligator",
            "tamaraw", "chinchilla", "salamander" };

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to Hangman");
    System.out.println("[1]START\n[0]EXIT");
    System.out.print("Please input your choice: ");
    int choice = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
    System.out.println();
    do {
        int miss = 0;
        if (choice == 1) {
            String wordRandom = words[ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(words.length)];
            String mute = "*".repeat(wordRandom.length());
            System.out.println(wordRandom);
            System.out.println("Note: use only small character/s\nHint: Animals");

            while (!mute.equals(wordRandom)) {
                System.out.print("(Guess) Enter a letter in word " + mute + " > ");
                String choice1 = input.nextLine();

                if (!wordHasCharacter(wordRandom, mute, choice1)) {
                    miss++;
                }
                mute = updateMuted(wordRandom, mute, choice1);
            }
            System.out.println("The word is " + wordRandom + "." + " You missed " + miss + " time.");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Do you want to guess another word? Enter [1]Yes or [0]No");
        System.out.print("Please input your choice: ");
        choice = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
    } while (choice != 0);
    System.out.println("Thank you!!");          }

public static boolean wordHasCharacter(String word, String muted, String key) {
    if (word.indexOf(key.charAt(0)) < 0) {
        System.out.println(key + " is not in the word.");
        return false;
    }
    if (muted.indexOf(key.charAt(0)) >= 0) {
        System.out.println(key + " is already in the word.");
    }
    return true;
}

public static String updateMuted(String word, String muted, String key) {
    StringBuilder update = new StringBuilder(muted);
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if (word.charAt(i) == key.charAt(0)) {
            update.setCharAt(i, key.charAt(0));
        }
    }
    return update.toString();
}
```